# How can I test a flash application?

Tags: flash, testing, cucumber

I have a swf file that should execute network calls when the user clicks on various stuff in it (and then do certain things based on the results of the calls).

What's my best option for automatically running tests to make sure that the flash application is behaving correctly?

This is with ActionScript 8, btw.  Not Flex.  I'm experienced with Cucumber.

Comment: Experience with cucumber is something i'll put on my resume when applying for porn roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you wire in calls to be able to trigger the UI programmatically you can use Selenium. (You basically make JS calls that get passed into Flash via ExternalInterface).

If you're after click testing the only thing I know of is a commercial product called Ranorex, though I have no experience with it.